# How to add package mahotas in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, mahotas

I want to add **mahotas** in my package of anaconda, 
so I installed this file **mahotas-1.4.3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl**  from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
then i put it in **C:\Anaconda3\Scripts** 
But when I ran this command **pip install mahotas-1.4.3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl** I got this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBTiD.png)

Comment: remove the downloaded file and let pip handle everything via `pip install mahotas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using **Anaconda 3**, the simplest and easiest way would be to use the `conda` command.

First open the **Anaconda Prompt** console window. It is always advisable to update your Anaconda library. To do that enter this in the console window:

`conda update conda`

Now to install **mahotas** using the following command:

`conda install mahotas`

Comment: You can use the same command to install any third party library. It is the best advantage of using conda. Also don't forget to update Anaconda using `conda update conda`. Doing so will update all the packages with the latest version. :D